# Validate object with static and dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, yup

I am trying to write a Yup validation schema of an object that it's Type looks like this

```
interface myObject {
  prop0: Date
  prop1: {
    nestedProp1: string
    nestedProp2: number
    [key: string]: string | number
  }
}
```

i tried this:

```js
yup.object({
  prop0: yup.string(),
  prop1: yup.object({
    nestedProp1: yup.string(),
    nestedProp2: yup.number(),
    // here goes the dynamic type validation ???
  })
})
```

im not able to write the correct validation for the dynamic key in `prop1`.

**EDIT:**
What im trying to achieve is basically feeding this type as a generic type for a function, and get it's schema using SchemaOf so i can type another param in this function (where i input my schema)

Here is a [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-goodall-87xjz?file=/src/index.ts) where im mimicking the real case scenario.

You can see that TS is complaining in line 39.

Comment: What did you try? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Added Sandbox for the real case scenario in the question

Answer (score 1):

Solution was simple.. i forgot to put .shape() in the yup validation for objects..